# I dont want the users to log in two times from Wordpress and cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

im developing a webapp using cakephp and i want to merge it with WordPress ,is there any solution that user will only login once (i dont want the users to log in two times.)

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress's `codex.wordpress.org` is big friend about anything related to the Wordpress system . you can import `Wordpress system into your web app` by looking at the following link:

[Integrate wordpress with your app](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website)

Wordpress says :

In order to transform regular PHP pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: thank you Arsh Singh! i will go through that

Comment: Why downvote? it's the solution he can go through. if you have better solution then post it , rather then clicking downvote.

Comment: This is not an answer. It's like someone asking "What does 'happy' mean" and you giving them a dictionary. It should be a comment at best. Downvote was not me though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  he asked for how he can join them , i gave him the link , where all the information is stored about how he can do that. Simple.